# Laravel A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.1

```
$variable1 = "1.000,00"; //<- this format error
$variable2 = "1.18";
$calc = $variable1 * $variable2;
```

Return calc error : **A non well formed numeric value encountered**

My PHO version : 7.1
Mu Laravel version : 5.5.20

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: two variable totals error a non well formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but after running your code, the output is `1.18`, because you're multiplying with `1` i.e `1.000` is same as `1`

```
<?php

$variable1 = "1.000,00"; //<- this format error
$variable2 = "1.18";
$calc = $variable1 * $variable2;

echo $calc;
```

Maybe this is what you're trying to do below

```
<?php

$variable1 = "1000.00"; //<- this format error
$variable2 = "1.18";
$calc = $variable1 * $variable2;

echo $calc;
```